# Why is the time zone in my JavaScript console incorrect?

Tags: javascript, timezone, timezone-offset, intl, ecmascript-intl

I am in the 'Asia/Shanghai' time zone and have set my computer system's time zone accordingly. However, when I retrieve the time zone using Chrome's console, the returned result is 'America/Chicago'.

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
'America/Chicago'
```

When I use Date(), I obtain the time in the correct time zone, and the obtained time zone offset through the function (new Date().getTimezoneOffset()) is -480, which is also correct.

```
new Date()
Fri Oct 13 2023 10:24:20 GMT+0800    <--Asia/Shanghai

new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
-480     <--Asia/Shanghai
```

Now my question is ,Why does Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone not match the time zone obtained from Date()?

How can I fix the issue with Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone returning the wrong time zone?

I tried on other computers, and the results were normal.

Comment: Have you tried other browsers? Are the results the same?

Comment: Yes, I tested it on other browsers on this computer, and it also gave incorrect results. However, when I switched to a different machine's browser, the results were normal.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood where the error was :p

Comment: @ziyunfei Why not provide it here if you have an answer? It is also interesting to non-Chinese people.

Comment: Are you using a current updated version of Chrome? Or some older version or alternative browser?  What version specifically? What OS are you running on, and are you setting a `TZ` environment variable somewhere?  If Chrome, have you inadvertently adjusted the [location settings](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/settings/locations/) - which can override the system time zone?